# Undefined control sequence, recently read \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, errors, undefined

I was writing a research paper. I faced the problem as below. How I will correct this?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You need to load the `graphicx` package in order to use `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Welcome :) explicitly, you'll need `\usepackage{graphicx}` at some point before your `\begin{document}` command